# Splitting type at a general fiber under blow up of a ruled surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ with Picard number one. Let $C_1, C_2$ be two rational curves in $X$ such that $TX\vert_{C_i}= \mathcal{O}(2)\oplus {\mathcal{O}(1)}^{\oplus d-2} \oplus \mathcal{O}^{n-d+1}$. Let $x= C_1 \cap C_2$. Let $\pi:T \to C_1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ be the blow up of $C_1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ at $(x, 0)$. Then we have a morphism $\tilde{f}:T \to X \times \mathbb{P}^1$.  Let $p_1: X \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to X$ be the projection. Let $g: T \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be the composition of   $\pi$ with the projection to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Question:
What can we say about the spilitting type of $(\tilde{f}^*p_1^*TX)\vert_{g^{-1}}(t)$ for a general $t$ ?